# Conectar base de datos sql con un login c#

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos, visual-studio, login

estoy tratando de conectar un login a una base de datos en c# con Microsoft SQL Server, este es el código:
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
..
.
.
.
..
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel1;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Practica3 { public partial class frm_login : Form { public frm_login() { InitializeComponent(); }

    SqlConnection conex = new SqlConnection(@"server= LAPTOP-26J31L29\SQLEXPRESS ; database = Login ; INTEGRATED SECURITY = true");

    private void btn_aceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conex.Open();
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT FROM USUARIO, CONTRASEÑA FROM PERSONA WHERE USUARIO = @vusuario AND CONTRASEÑA = @vcontraseña", conex);
            comando.ParametersAddWithValue("@vusuario", txtb_usuario.Text);
            comando.ParametersAddWithValue("@vcontraseña", txtb_contraseña.Text);

            SqlDataReader lector = comando.ExecuteReader();
            if (lector.Read())
            {
                conex.Close();
                Principal pantalla = new Principal();
                pantalla.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usuario no encontrado");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conex.Close();
        }
    }

    private void btn_salir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

}

La cosa es que me da un error en esta parte:

```
comando.ParametersAddWithValue("@vusuario", txtb_usuario.Text);
comando.ParametersAddWithValue("@vcontraseña", txtb_contraseña.Text);
```

Me dice que los ParametersAddWithValue les falta una directiva using pero ya tengo puesto el

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Entonces, no sé cual es el problema ahí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola como una recomendación hacerlo con un proceso almacenado en SlqServer.

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT @vusuario FROM USUARIO, CONTRASEÑA FROM PERSONA WHERE USUARIO = @vusuario AND CONTRASEÑA = @vcontraseña", conex);
```

intenta con este formato

```
comando.Parameters.Add("@vusuario", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtb_usuario.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@vcontraseña", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtb_contraseña.Text;
```

Comment: Gracias, ya me corre el login, ahora tengo otro problema jaja :&, pongo el usuario y contraseña correctos, pero no me logea, me sale un error diciendo `Incorrect syntax near the keyword FROM`

Comment: Tienes 2 Tablas distintas para persona y contraseña o es todo una misma tabla usuarios?

Comment: Edit: ya pude, gracias